# Cannot enter nvALT options anymore

Tags: macos, preferences

I changed nvALT to be displayed in the menu bar and set the option that it is not to be displayed in the Dock anymore.

I wanted to change the settings back and unchecked the options that nvALT is shown as symbol in the menu bar. However, now it is neither in the menu bar nor the Dock, and I can not access the options anymore to change it. When I open nvALT, the option menu of the App that was open previously is shown in the menu bar.

Any idea how I can get into nvALT's preferences?

I tried to delete the app (deleted the nvALT folder from the /Library), however, the original app preferences are still saved somewhere, I just cannot find where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to open the preferences by just pressing ⌘,.

If that doesn't work, try running `defaults write net.elasticthreads.nv ShowDockIcon -bool true` or deleting `~/Library/Preferences/net.elasticthreads.nv.plist`.

Comment: thanks, `defaults write net.elasticthreads.nv ShowDockIcon -bool true` worked like a charm!